# what's the difference between the ProtoBufBuilder.clear().mergeFrom(value.getBytes(), 0, value.getLength()) and mergeFrom.(value.getBytes())

Tags: hadoop, protocol-buffers

`ProtoBufBuilder.clear().merge(value.getBytes(), 0, value.getLength())` works well

but

`ProtoBufBuilder.clear().merge(value.getBytes())` read few data from the proto file.

Comment: In your example, what is `value`?

Comment: @MarcGravell input is sequence file.